# Change language in Unity 5 (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

i am making a calendar app. When i write this in my code `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek`
i get the current day (Monday), but how can i change it so it writes "Monday" on a different language (e.g. Norwegian)?
The same problem goes of course for the months too.

Answer (score 0):

[CultureInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nb-NO");
var day = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my day :)

Comment: How ever "de-DE" gives you Danish, not norwegian, but found out that "nb-NO" is norwegain [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx), here you can see the different languages and thier tag